# Data Core order by with when case

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm learning how to fetching data with Core Data in Swift5. How can I convert the following sorting which use the "case when"?

```
SELECT * 
FROM City
ORDER BY CASE
     WHEN name = 'PQR' THEN 0
     WHEN name = 'Others' THEN 1
     ELSE 2 END,
     surname ASC
```

I know that I can do multiple fetch where each one filter on the different name and the final one on all other names. I would like a way to do it in a single operation

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this kind of sorting in a CoreData fetch.

You have two options here; either do your fetch first then sort after, or maintain an extra property in your managed object for sorting purposes.

edit: One other option that would work in your case above is just use three seperate fetches.